# How to indicate there is more text in a single-line C# winforms textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, textbox

Sometimes, a fixed-width, single-line textbox in winforms with C# Visual Studio 2010 contains just the right width of characters that the boundary between two characters (or words) lines up with the edge of the textbox making it impossible to tell there is more text without clicking and dragging with the mouse.

What are the best practices for indicating there is more text?

Comment: This is exactly how it works in every other application. Not sure why you feel the need to change it. This is one of those attempts to work around the standard UI that provides only minimal benefits and adds a lot of extra complexity.

Comment: @Cody Gray People using my application have gotten confused and data has been lost because of this "standard" behavior.

Comment: Do the people using your application have that same problem with *other* applications? Because if not, there is something seriously wrong with your application's design. Everything else works the same way, and your users manage to do just fine there. You need to identify what makes yours *different* and fix that instead.

Comment: @ryantm Go ahead and make your UI better! Just because something "is" doesn't mean it's "best". Otherwise nothing would evolve.

I use a basic text-length check against the textbox size to make a decision on auto-ellipsis as well as adding the full text as a hover tip. So the tip only appears if the text exceeds the space available. Works great. I don't have the code handy but can DM you if you still want it after all this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either simply don't use use a Single line Textbox

Or as I did.. created a custom text box control inheriting the TextBox Class and made it to look like `Shekha...` when it overflows and it is not focused and when it has focus set the Text back to `Shekhar_Pro` or whatever it was originally.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the code in this codeproject.com article:

[Auto Ellipsis](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AutoEllipsis.aspx)

The author extends TextBox to create a text box control that shortens text to fit and does a reasonable job of using ellipses to indicate it had to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be a real problem, the user typed in the text herself a minute ago.  She *knows* that the text got clipped.

Do make sure that you don't use a TextBox to display text yourself.  That requires a Label.  And it has the AutoEllipsis property to automatically display ... if the text doesn't fit the MaximumSize of the label.  And an automatic tooltip to display the rest.

Comment: Unless someone else, who has dragged the border of the dialog so it is wider, entered the text. Then other users won't be able to tell.

Comment: Or it's a pre-filled form that the user can edit. Any number of scenarios make this a possible problem worth fixing in my opinion. Too many otherwise-good programmers belittle good UI design.